# Is there a way to add a title to a dataframe spanning across multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say you have any pandas dataframe with `4 columns`, and you want to add a header row to it. Is there a way to do this?

Here is an example dataframe for you to work with:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

[image]

I'd like to add something on top like the `September` header above.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `MultiIndex` here

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Sep'],df.columns])
df
Out[666]: 
  Sep            
    A   B   C   D
0  33  91  64  27
1  46   5  32  40
2  64  55  13  13
3  65  80  82  64
4  78  21  55  10
5  15  15  55  32
6  65  18  11  30
7  32  37  83   8
8  82  59   2  87
9   9  69  56  70
```

Comment: What if I wanted to have multiple headers, each with different column headers? how would I go about adding those extra column headers?